# Display border along header and footer of Kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am adding columns dynamically in the kendo ui grid. At the top of the grid the default text is displayed 'Drag a column header and drop it here to group by that column'.

At the footer of the grid the paging details are displayed including icon for navigation.

But, the grid is not displaying the border at the top and bottom, means the default text displayed at the top of the grid is not having the border and also the footer including the paging control the border is missing.

How can I add that border.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mind showing some example on how you generate the grid? You might use JSFiddle or JSBin

Comment: Actually, I am not sure if I can post my code here as it is really big. What I will try to create a sample code in similar form. But is it that some css needs to be changed. I did modified some css files of kendo , so would that have caused the issue.                                                                                                                                  Also, I have added groupable true, but that is also not working. Any idea what could be the reason for this

Comment: This is somewhat I am trying create grid                           ($(document.getElementById(divId))).kendoGrid({
            columns: columns,
            dataSource: masterData,
            pageable: {
                pageSize: 10
            },
            groupable: true,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
            scrollable: true,             
            selectable: "multiple",
            dataBound: RowDataBound,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "MasterColID"
                }
            }
        }).data("kendoGrid");

Comment: Styles for grid header are mostly defined in `k-grid-header` and for pager are `k-grid-pager`. About `groupable` I would need to see how did you define it :-(

Comment: Really thanks for the quick reply. I will check in the css for thosse values. But for groupable I didn't understand much. I have just added property with value true. Do I need to add anything extra. Please suggest me on this.

Comment: No, by default that's it. Then you can drag and drop a column header into _Drag a column header and drop it here to group by that column_ and the grid will group all value that have the same value for that column. And I said by default because you can initialize the grid for grouping by certain columns on display.

Comment: Really Thanks OnaBai for your help. I was able to get the borders for header and footer. Actually I want border for the text that is displayed at the top pf the grid. Means I want border for this text 'Drag a column header and drop it here to group by that column'. Please if you can help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For styling group header o a grid you need to include the definitions in `k-group-header`. Something like:

```
.k-grouping-header {
    border: 5px groove red;
}
```

Comment: Really Really thanks to you OnaBai for your help. I really was looking for this. Really thanks for the help.